# Десериализация больших файлов

Tags: c#, json, .net-core

Есть у меня к примеру большой файл с объектами.
Мне нужно проверить содержит ли какой нибудь объект название города.

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("city.list.json", FileMode.Open))
{
    var citys = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<City>>(fs);

    var result = citys.Where(x => x.name == city).FirstOrDefault();

    if (result != null)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    { 
        return false;
    }
}
```

Как мне загружать к примеру по 1000 обьектов, и если ничего не нашло то загружать следующие 1000 объектов?
Или можно как то установить предел памяти к примеру 10 Мб?

Comment: `содержит ли какой нибудь объект название города` Для этого не обязательно парсить, просто в файле поиском пройдитесь по нужному вам слову.

Comment: Используйте [Utf8JsonReader](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-use-dom-utf8jsonreader-utf8jsonwriter#use-utf8jsonreader)

Comment: Альтернативно для десереализации можно использовать модель, которая содержит только нужные свойства.

Comment: Для поиска в любом случае файл нужно загружать в память. А если у меня файл 2гб, а оперативной памяти 1гб что делать тогда? Только разбивать файл на мелкие файлы и потом их по очереди загружать?

Comment: Потоковый ридер не грузит целиком в память, а считывает кусками.

Comment: Это streamreader который?

Comment: >>>>> Utf8JsonReader  <<<<<

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: А можете набросать решение на S.T.Json? У меня с наскоку не вышло (ну если только не читать по токенам всё, но это как-то лениво, особенно если объект сложный).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

У меня не получилось с наскоку на System.Text.Json*, поэтому вот вам решение на Newtonsoft.Json.

Основная хитрость вот какая: с одной стороны, нельзя читать через `JsonConvert` или `JsonSerializer.Deserialize`, т. к. это прочитает весь файл в память. С другой стороны, читать по одному токену через `JsonTextReader` тоже неохота, т. к. придётся слишком подробно разбирать каждую запись, и проводить десериализацию практически вручную.

Поэтому я остановился на комбинированном решении. `JsonSerializer` умеет читать частичные данные из `JsonTextReader`'а, а значит, его можно попросить прочитать всего один город из списка. Таким образом, можно организовать ленивую последовательность городов.

Правда, нам придётся читать начало и конец массива по токенам, но это небольшая плата за экономию памяти.

Наши токены будет выглядеть так:

```
начало массива ([)
начало объекта ({)
- тут сам объект City
конец объекта (})
начало объекта ({)
- тут ещё один объект City
конец объекта (})
начало объекта ({)
- и так далее
конец объекта (})
конец массива (])
```

Итак, получается следующий код:

```
IEnumerable<City> ReadCitiesLazy(string path)
{
    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    using var tr = File.OpenText(path); // открываем файл
    using var jr = new JsonTextReader(tr); // натравливаем на него токенизатор
    jr.Read(); // жёстко проверяем формат: убеждаемся, что у нас тут идёт начало массива
    if (jr.TokenType != JsonToken.StartArray)
        throw new FormatException("Array start expected");
    jr.Read(); // переходим к следующему токену
    while (jr.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject) // это или начало объекта
    {                                             // если так, читаем объект одним махом
        yield return serializer.Deserialize<City>(jr);
        if (jr.TokenType != JsonToken.EndObject)  // тут должен быть конец объекта
            throw new FormatException("Object end expected");
        jr.Read();                                // переходим к следующему токену в цикле
    }
    if (jr.TokenType != JsonToken.EndArray)       // не начало объекта => конец массива
        throw new FormatException("Array end expected");
}
```

Всё, можно пользоваться:

```
foreach (var city in ReadCitiesLazy(path))
    Console.WriteLine(city.Name);
```

---

*Вот [этот пример](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-use-dom-utf8jsonreader-utf8jsonwriter#read-from-a-stream-using-utf8jsonreader) показывает, как «вручную» читать из файла, перемежая операции чтения из `Utf8JsonReader` и пересоздание этого самого `Utf8JsonReader`, но это у меня не получается автоматизировать для чтения произвольного объекта. Впрочем, есть [тикет](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30328) на github, который говорит именно об этом. А чтение объекта из `Utf8JsonReader` можно сделать как в удалённом ответе @Alexander Petrov: `var city = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<City>(ref reader);`.